# Outlook Word Editor Fluent UI

Tags: outlook

Is it possible to repurpose the context menu of a Rich Text Format mail item? I observed that the context menu that shows up when I right click on an attachment inside a rich text format email is that of the Word Editor. How can I access the context menu of that word editor from my outlook?

Edit: I have added a screencap of which context menu I am referring to.[image: screen capture of context menu for a Rich Text Format Mail Item]

Comment: Could you post a screenshot of the context menu you need to repurpose?

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev Hi, I have updated a screenshot as per requested. I hope it will make things clearer! More specifically, I need to intercept the [Save As...] Option

Answer (score 0):

You can read more about repurposing built-in controls in the [Temporarily Repurpose Commands on the Office Fluent Ribbon](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb462633(v=office.12).aspx) article in MSDN.

Also, you can read about the *startFromScratch* mode in the following series of articles that describe the Fluent UI in-depth:

1. [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 1 of 3)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338202(v=office.12).aspx)
2. [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 2 of 3)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338199(v=office.12).aspx)
3. [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 3 of 3)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa722523(v=office.12).aspx)

For built-in `idMso` values take a look at the [Extending the User Interface in Outlook 2010](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2010/ee692172%28v%3Doffice.14%29) article.

Comment: Thank you for the links, I have actually gone through that article a number of times as I have been repurposing quite a number of other components. However, I could not find the corresponding idMso for that particular one I need, which was why I posted a question here, at my wits end.

I hope your links can also be of help to others!

Comment: Take a look at the [Extending the User Interface in Outlook 2010](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2010/ee692172%28v%3doffice.14%29) article for built-in idMso values.